# CHECK Constraint combination of two fields fails on EITHER field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to prevent a record from being inserted when two fields are not defined. If either one is defined but not the other than that is acceptable, BOTH cannot be left NULL however. I am using the following CONSTRAINT ...

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_person_institution] CHECK (person_id IS NOT NULL AND institution_id IS NOT NULL)
```

This constraint prevents me from inserting a record if EITHER field is left undefined (NULL).

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. And you insert _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you want is

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_person_institution]
    CHECK (NOT(person_id IS NULL AND institution_id IS NULL));
```

Comment: Ah ah that was close.

Comment: 5 seconds in them @GMB . At least our answers aren't identical this time. ;)

Comment: Yes I see what you refer to! Here both answers are different and valid.

Answer (score 3):

> If either one is defined but not the other than that is acceptable, BOTH cannot be left NULL however.

You want `OR`, not `AND`:

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_person_institution] 
    CHECK (person_id IS NOT NULL OR institution_id IS NOT NULL)
```